# Как привязать графический элемент в Windows Forms к границам формы?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Объясню только самую суть, не вдаваясь в подробности!

Я нарисовал внутри формы прямоугольник. Мне нужно, чтобы он всегда был посередине между левой и правой границами формы и чуть выше нижней границы. Главное, чтобы при растягивании формы мой прямоугольник следовал за границами, а не стоял на месте.
У меня получается вот так, что он остается на месте:

[image: до и после]

Вот обработчик события Paint (fGame - это имя формы):

```
private void fGame_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics dc = e.Graphics;      
            dc.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, plr); // plr - Прямоугольник           
        }
```

Вот обработчик таймера, в котором инициализируются координаты прямоугольника и вызывается метод Invalidate():

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            plrX = Bounds.Right / 2; // Координата X прямоугольника plr
            plrY = Bounds.Bottom - 5; // Координата Y прямоугольника plr
            Invalidate();
        }
```

По задумке таймер должен каждые 500 мс вычислять координаты для прямоугольника и, вызывая метод Invalidate(), перерисовывать форму.

Comment: Зачем же таймер то? есть же куча всяких событий, можно же просто отлавливать событие изменения размеры формы

Comment: Попробовал инициализировать координаты X и Y в обработчике события Resize. Безрезультатно. При растягивании формы мой белый кирпич лежит и не шевелится(

Comment: а дебагером смотреть пробовали? событие отрабатывает?